# Difference between Bear and tolerate

Tags: word-difference

> Some people bear/tolerate the free riders who refuse to contribute.

What is better word choice and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you meant "some people"...

When not talking about the animal, ***bear*** usually means *carry*, but it also carries that meaning to lots of metaphorical senses. So, to "bear a characteristic" means to have that characteristic, metaphorical saying you are carrying it. To "bear a load" is to carry a load, and to "bear up" is to support it solidly - and by metaphor, to manage well under that load.

(I'm not sure if the navigational meaning derives from *carry* or not, but we can ignore that for now, as your question is about the *carry* sense)

One of those metaphorical meanings is *put up with*, best understood in the negative possibility "I couldn't ***bear*** it", which means "I would be unable to carry the metaphorical (presumably emotional) load of it". This end up as effectively the same meaning as ***tolerate***. *Tolerate* is a slightly more formal choice. *Tolerate* is also preferable if there's no modal verb - *bear* will often be used with the modal *can* or its relative *could*. Situations in which it is used without, or with a different modal, are less common.

Answer (score 1):

The *literal* meaning of ***to bear*** is ***to carry***, which can reasonably easily be extended to focus more specifically on the ***sustain the heavy load of some burden*** being carried aspect of that literal sense.

But when we look at the more metaphoric extension of usages such as ***to bear the burden of guilt***, it seems to me these are much more likely to occur *in the negative* (to be *unable* to bear such a burden).

And with even *more* metaphoric usages such as *I can't bear the way he looks at me*, I'd say these are almost *entirely* restricted to "negating" contexts...

> 1: *Some people **bear** the freeriders* - NON-IDIOMATIC
>    2: *Some people **can't bear** the freeriders* - Unlikely, but not "unnatural"
>    3: *Some people **won't bear** the freeriders* - NON-IDIOMATIC
>    4: *Some people **tolerate** the freeriders* - TOTALLY NATURAL ENGLISH
>    5: *Some people **can't tolerate** the freeriders* - Unlikely, but not "unnatural"
>    6: *Some people **won't tolerate** the freeriders* - TOTALLY NATURAL ENGLISH
>    7: *Some people **won't put up with** the freeriders* - TOTALLY NATURAL ENGLISH

Note that the article in ***the*** freeriders is totally optional, and would often be omitted - unless the context is *very specifically* about some particular set of "freeriders", but even there we'd have to consider whether "some people" are objecting to just *those* freeriders, or to "freeriders in general".

Comment: You don't appear to have considered non-negated modals... "Some people **can bear** the freeriders" - only unnatural/unlikely if the sentence ends there (as is "can't bear") - if it continues with a verb, it becomes natural: "some people can bear the freeriders taking handouts from..." Basically, that sense is natural and can be idiomatic as long as there's a suitable modal verb along with it. I think.

Comment: @SamBC: I thought it was already clear from the examples I gave, and the accompanying "explanation", that *Some people **can** bear the freeriders* (or other auxiliaries such as ***will / do** bear*) also wouldn't be idiomatic. The important point is that ***negation makes a big difference***. If you think otherwise, maybe I'll try to think of some relevant search terms for Google Books to back up my position.

Comment: It makes a big difference - but I was pointing out that it's less of a difference *if the sentence doesn't end at 'freeriders'*. Also if other nouns replace 'freeriders'. "I can bear the pain" is, I believe, not so unusual (also apparently a song title, but there you go). My point is that negation isn't all there is to it in the examples you give. "Bear the burden of guilt" I've definitely come across plenty in the third person without any modal, by the by.

Comment: I specifically cited the non-negated example *bear the [burden of] guilt* as "intermediate" to the more extremely metaphorical sense of ***to bear = tolerate / put up with***. In the case of ***I can bear the pain*** I'd say there are effectively two different possible "nuances" - *It is **acceptable to me** that there should be this level of pain*, or *I am **able to withstand** this level of pain*. But I'm sure that whichever precise sense might be intended, they'll both be far less common than negated *I **can't** bear the pain*, even though in practice I'm probably *already* "bearing" it.

Comment: (But almost certainly not ***tolerating*** it without complaint! :)

Comment: Less common, probably, but not non-idiomatic, and not really "unlikely" - except in the sense that people are less likely to want to express that meaning.

Comment: I think we're probably mostly just arguing over the precise implications of "non-idiomatic". But given this is a site for learners, I think they should be more interested in what native speakers are or aren't likely to say, rather than whether or not something they *don't* often say is actually "valid".

Comment: You're probably right, but I think something can be idiomatic even if it's unlikely to be said - just because the need for it is unusual. If the need does arise, they say it that way. So we would rarely say "the sky is green today", but if the sky did happen to turn green, that's how we'd say it. Well, probably with some swearwords thrown in. Thus, "the sky is green today" is not non-idiomatic, the cause just doesn't come up. "I can bear the pain" is, I think, one of the most likely ways to actually communicate that idea, along with "I can cope with the pain" and "I can stand the pain".